# How to cut the wax from this cheese?

Tags: equipment, cheese, cheese-making

(I am new to Europe so please forgive me for being not knowing).

I have this cheese 
[image]

I asked here before how to eat it and people answered me, but when it comes to real life I had a problem removing the wax, because it really stuck to the cheese!

I like the taste and I want to try it again, but this time I want to ask you how to remove this wax. What I did before is but it rounded, but that removes cheese and obvious my way was wrong.

I hope you can show me a video or something to make it easier for me because my English is not so good. Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

I usually cut the wheel of cheese, wax and all. So cut a quarter or a half off, depending on how much you want to eat. Then, you can simply peel the wax off. Clean the knife of wax before using it again to cut cheese you'll be eating.

**EDIT:**

Another solution (upon a quick Googling to search for an answer to @Joe's issue in the comment) could be to use a vegetable peeler to peel layers of problematic wax off until getting to cheese goodness: http://nomenu.com/?p=43877

Comment: Be warned that this doesn't always go so well for all cheeses.  If the wax layer isn't thick enough and the mold the cheese was pressed in has sufficient texture to it, the wax may end up shredding when you try to peel it off.  (Manchego & Iberico come to mind, although they don't have the rounded over corners like Gouda & the one in the picture)